# SQLITE_ERROR SQL error or missing database (table food has no column named price)

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, jdbc

I am trying to make a budgeting application, where users can enter items such as food and various utilities. I am using Intellij Ultimate.

I don't understand this error at all. I mean, I kind of  but I don't understand WHY it says:

```
SQLITE_ERROR SQL error or missing database (table food has no column named price)
```

when I try to insert or select from the food table. I clearly create the 'price' column.

Here is my code:

```
    /**
 * Database class
 */

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.DatabaseMetaData;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Database {
    public static void connect() {
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            // db parameters
            String url = "jdbc:sqlite:budget.db";
            // create a connection to the database
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);

            System.out.println("Connection to SQLite has been established.");

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            try {
                if (conn != null) {
                    conn.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
    public static void insertFood(String name, double quantity, double price) {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO food(name, quantity, price) VALUES(?,?,?)";
        try {
            String url = "jdbc:sqlite:budget.db";
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            pstmt.setString(1, name);
            pstmt.setDouble(2, quantity);
            pstmt.setDouble(3, price);
            pstmt.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("Items have been inserted into food table");
        } catch(SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    public static void selectAllFood() {
        String sql = "SELECT name, quantity, price FROM food";

        try {
            String url = "jdbc:sqlite:budget.db";
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

            while(resultSet.next()) {
                System.out.println(resultSet.getString("name") + "\t" +
                        resultSet.getDouble("quantity") + "\t" +
                        resultSet.getDouble("price"));
            }
        } catch(SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    public static void createNewDatabase(String fileName) {
        String url = "jdbc:sqlite:C:/Users/Jim/IdeaProjects/BudgetPro/" + fileName;

        try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url)) {
            if (conn != null) {
                DatabaseMetaData meta = conn.getMetaData();
                System.out.println("The driver name is " + meta.getDriverName());
                System.out.println("A new database has been created.");
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    public static void createFoodTable() {
        // SQLite connection string
        String url = "jdbc:sqlite:budget.db";

        // SQL statement for creating a new table
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS food (\n"
                + " id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,\n"
                + " name text NOT NULL ,\n"
                + " quantity real,\n"
                + " price real\n"
                + ");";

        try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
             Statement stmt = conn.createStatement()) {
            // create a new table
            stmt.execute(sql);
            System.out.println("Food table has been established.");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    public static void createUtilitiesTable() {
        String url = "jdbc:sqlite:budget.db";
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS utilities (\n"
                + " id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL ,\n"
                + " name text NOT NULL,\n"
                + " price real\n"
                + ");";

        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
             Statement stmt = connection.createStatement()) {
            stmt.execute(sql);
            System.out.println("Utilities table has been established.");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Main class
 */
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Database.connect();
        Database.createFoodTable();
        Database.createUtilitiesTable();

        Database.insertFood("Pompano", 2, 7.99);
    }
}
```

When I run this, my output is:

```
Connection to SQLite has been established.
Food table has been established.
Utilities table has been established.
[SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (table food has no column named price)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: I think the `\n` in your SQL code is causing errors

Comment: Why do you have a bunch of static methods, though? You can share the state of the current `Connection` variable within the `Database` class.

Comment: Do a `.schema` command on the table to display its actual definition, and add that to your post.

Comment: cricket_007 what do you mean?

Comment: The newlines? You don't need them... Then, basically, `static` methods aren't entirely necessary. You can make a `new Database(fileName)`, then you can define a constructor such that a method `createTables()` would be called. And also, do `List<Food> foods = database.getAllFoods()`, for example. It's all Object Oriented Design that you'll just need to learn.

Comment: What the heck?! Why bother using OOP on this? It would be much simpler if I defined my functions all in one file and did it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably created this table before without the price column.  You should drop that table or rename it to `food2`.

If renaming it solves your problem, drop table `food` and recreate it.

Good luck with it...